# Система электронной очереди на php

Tags: php

Реально ли сделать такую систему на PHP, что бы она не онлайн записывала, а локально?
Пример:
Человек пришел в офис тур компании, нажал на планшете "записаться в очередь", система автоматом записала посетителя к менее загруженному / свободному менеджеру, сгенерировала номер очереди, и всю эту инфу распечатала как талон в pos терминале.
Да, еще и большое табло с очередью показывало состояние очереди.
Возможно ли это реализовать средствами php? Не извращение ли это?)))
Спасибо.

Comment: А что такое "локально" и чем это отличается от "онлайн" ? Вообще все зависит от драйверов чекового принтера и "большого табло". подо что драйвера найдете, на том и будете писать

Comment: @Mike "локально" это всмысле только в офисе компании. Не будит сайта и тд. Типо как в банках электроные очереди. А вообще реально ли на php как то отправить данные на терминал что бы терминал номер очереди (что то типо инвойса) распечатал?

Comment: Это от вашего терминала зависит. Клиент же что бы распечатать очередь на нем что то вероятно должен сам нажимать. И в это время терминал по хорошему должен послать запрос на сервер а тот ему ответить. А разницы для web (если терминал конечно по http готов общаться) вообще нет в интернете он или локально. Прописываете в локальном DNS любое имя сайта какое захотите с внутренним ip сервера или вообще обращаетесь к нему прямо по ip

Comment: @Mike понятно. Спасибо

Comment: Если это делается "локально" и идет работа с какими либо вспомогательными устройствами, то лучше посмотреть sdk или библиотеки для данного устройства, на чем они написаны. Думаю вам целесообразнее будет писать на плюсах или питоне. Для них есть много документации.